# How to select box select value in <c:set> tag

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

in my jsp page i have a select box

```
<select id="quantity" name="quantity" onchange="alert(quantity.value)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

alert print selected value and , now i'm setting this value into `c:set` tag

```
 <c:set var="quantity1" value="" >// how to set quantity value hear
```

Actually i'm trying `value="${quantity.value}"` but not success.

give me suggestion

Comment: Are you using Jquery ? In Jquery the exact syntax would be, `$('select[quantity] option:selected').text();`

Comment: yes i'm using jquery, but how to set value in <c:set value="?">

Comment: Bro i suppose you use the proper tagging next time ;) i have mentioned in my previous comment , `var value=$('select[quantity] option:selected').text(); $('#targetTag').attr('value',value);  `

Comment: `#targetTag` this should be the id of your <c:set > tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have set the quantity value as request attribute and access in the jstl as follows

```
// In Action class/server side/or top of jsp
request.setAttribute("quantityvalue","1");

//In jsp
<c:set var="quantity1" value="${quantityvalue}" >
```

You can not access dom fields using jstl. As jstl is for server side.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set value to jsp's <c:set> tag on client-side (javascript/jquery). JSP is processed on server-side. <c:set> is not a part of rendered html.